Stability of flow map
$\DeclareMathOperator\Diff{Diff}$Setting:
Let $(M,g)$ be a compact and connected $C^{\infty}$-Riemannian manifold.  Let $d_g$ denote the induced shorted path metric and equip $C^{\infty}(M)$ with the supremum norm ($\|f\|:=\max_{x \in M}\, |f(x)|$).

Let $\mathcal{X}(M)\subset L(C^{\infty}(M),C^{\infty}(M))$ be the set of smooth functions on $M$ which we equip with the metric induced by the operator norm $\|\cdot\|_{op}$.  Let $\Diff_0(M)$ denote the set of orientation-preserving diffeomorphisms on $M$ which we equip with the uniform metric
$$
d_{\infty}(f,g):= \sup_{x\in M}\, d_g(f(x),g(x)).
$$

Question
Let $\operatorname{Exp}:(\mathcal{X}(M),\|\cdot\|_{op})\rightarrow (\Diff_0(M),d_{\infty})$ mapping any vector field $V\in \mathcal{X}$ to a diffeomorphism $\varphi_V:M\to M$ given by $\varphi(x):=x_1^x$ where
$
\dot{x}_t^x = V(x_t^x) \mbox{ and }  x_0^x = x.
$

Is the map $\operatorname{Exp}$ locally Lipschitz?  If so, are there estimates over ``sufficiently nice'' compact subsets of $\mathcal{X}(M)$?

Which metrics are you using?

Ah I'm equipped each space with their uniform metrics.

Then spell it out: There are infinitely many inequivalent uniform metrics in this setting.

@MoisheKohan I added details, and to simplify the setting, I just assumed $M$ to be compact and connected.

What is $\mathcal X$? I think there is confusion between maps $M\to M$ and vector fields.

What's written is based on confusion between maps of manifolds, vector fields and (presumably) time 1 maps induced by vector fields. Your $d_g$ is just the standard Riemannian distance function written in an odd form. In this form, your question does not belong to MO.

@MoisheKohan  Apologies for the messy post I have corrected my question.  It should be well-posed now.

I do not understand your definition of $\mathcal{X}$. What precisely is the operator norm in this case? One interpretation is as follows: since elements of $\mathcal{X}$ is identified with vector fields on $M$, and $C^\infty(M)$ is equipped with the uniform norm, the operator norm of the vector field $v$ may, potentially, mean $\sup_{|f| \leq 1} |v(f)|$. But this quantity is $+\infty$ for any non-zero vector field $v$.

@WillieWong Why would this norm blow-up for non-zero vector field?  In any case, to me this norm seemed natural on $\mathcal{X}$ but if its defective, may I ask: what's a good choice of a metric on $\mathcal{X}$.

@ABIM: let $p$ be a point where $v \neq 0$, choose local coordinates where $v|p = \frac{\partial}{\partial x^1}$. Let your functions $f\epsilon$ be such that, in a neighborhood of $p$, it equations $f_\epsilon(x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n) = \epsilon \sin( \epsilon^{-2} x_1)$. They converge to $0$ uniformly, but $v(f)|_p$ blows up. // Since you are in the Riemannian category, why not just take the (sup of) the Riemannian length of the vector field?

Fundamentally your question is really just the question of Lipschitz dependence on parameters for ordinary differential equations, dressed up in some geometry language which are not that significant. If you have access to Henri Cartan's Differential Calculus textbook, this is quite elegantly treated in Chapter 2, section 1.10 and 1.11. // Hartman's book has a discussion of $C^1$ dependence in Chapter 2, but if you are careful you can trace through the proof and track down the Lipschitz dependence (which requires a bit less hypotheses).

@WillieWong Ah that's a good point.  So basically locally, this is just Gronwall then...

I would say, pretty much. One just have to be careful in designing your norm/metric on $\mathcal{X}$ to be the one that works.
